# when i click the button the whole webpage moved to another webpage like a slide

Tags: javascript, php

I have two html pages: Page1.html, Page2.html. I would like to get the page 2.html when i click the button in page1 with slide effect transition. I have found a lot of plugins and solutions to slide between two divs or slide within a container but what I need is a complete page change.

```js
// Author: Max McKinney
// Version: 1.0
// Description: Fades the page from a given color to show the content and fades out to the given color.
// Requires: jQuery

(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.mPageTransition = function(options) {

        // Grab the settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            color: "#ffc107",
            fadeOutTime: 300,
            fadeInTime: 300
        }, options)

        // Get the body reference and get the original background color as we will be changing that during the transition
        var body = $('body');
        var originalBackgroundColor = $(body).css("background-color");

        // Due to the css the body is initially hidden so we will fade it in. This prevents and "flickering" from occuring
        $(body).css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(settings.fadeInTime);

        // Intercept all link clicks to fade page out
        $("a").click(function(e) {
            // Get the original link location and stop it from occuring
            var link = this;
            e.preventDefault();

            // First fade body content away, fade the background color to the defined custom color. Once it has fade in, fade it away and then follow the link href
            $(body).animate({
                "background-color": settings.color,
                "opacity": 0
            }, settings.fadeInTime, function() {
                // Fade background color back to orginal and once finished follow link
                $(body).animate({"background-color": originalBackgroundColor}, settings.fadeOutTime, function() {
                    var href = $(link).attr("href");
                    location.href=href;
                })
            });

        });

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: no i found plugins like https://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/

Comment: but they are moving the divs in single page.but i want to move another page with button click with slide transition effect

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Cross-fading-Page-Transition-Effects-jQuery-M-PageTransition/index.html

Comment: the above link is suits for my problem but i want slide effect not fading effect

Comment: var settings = $.extend({
            color: "#ffc107",
            fadeOutTime: 300,
            fadeInTime: 300
        }, options)

Comment: could you please write all these information in your question.  And it will be good if you create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/azista/ygLc84db/

Comment: Please edit your *question* don't keep adding comments.  Edit your question to add in the info from the comments, then delete the comments.  Also read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for editing your question.  JavaScript and the document on page1 will be destroyed as the document and JavaScript for page2 loads so what you want is probably not possible without using a custom browser application where you control the page rendering.